# How to create gtk.STOCK_* buttons from a modified list of strings?

Tags: python, string, variables, pygtk, gtk

I'm trying to create a simple program that displays all the gtk stock buttons.
I copied the list of stock id's from:
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-ButtonWidget.html
pasted them into a .txt file
and created a list from the file:
    
    `stock_file = open('stock_buttons.txt')

    stock_button_list = stock_file.readlines()`

    
This makes a list which looks like:
    `stock_button_list[0] = '  STOCK_DIALOG_INFO/n'`  
So I concatenate the 'gtk.' prefix and slice off the excess
Then I create the buttons with a for loop:
    
    `for each_button in stock_button_list:

        self.button1 = gtk.Button(None, each_button)`

But Python interprets each_button as a string and I get a bunch of buttons with the stock ids as just labels. : (
It works if I manually create a list of the stock id names:
 `stock_button_list = [gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_INFO, gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING, etc.]`  
My list is fine and looks the same as the stock ids but it is a list of strings.

**How can I get Python to recognise strings as the global variables for stock button ids??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple:

```
for button in stock_button_list:
    self.button1=gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk,button))
```

Using getattr you can access all the attributes of an object or module by name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  However I'm still getting an Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute?

Comment: Check that the list of buttons in stock_button_list is in this format: ['STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING','STOCK_DIALOG_INFO',...'STOCK_XXXXXXX'], you use getattr to get an attribute inside the gtk module, so the atrribute name should be an existent attribute. Probably your list is using 'gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING' instead 'STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING'

Comment: Got it. The last item in my list was an empty string.  Thanks so much for your help!  SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> a='STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING'
>>> getattr(gtk, a)
'gtk-dialog-warning'
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
As Revil said, use getattr(obj,name) to access gtk.STOCK_* buttons with a list of strings.
Just make sure that every item in your list matches a valid name in the object, otherwise an AttributeError will be raised.

Here is my finished program.  It simply shows all the stock buttons.
*Note: In order for this program to work you need to create stock_buttons.txt in the same dir.  Simply paste the list of stock ids from the link in the question above into a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# stock_buttons.py
# Simple program to show all stock buttons
# Author: oringe

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class stock_buttons:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        self.window.set_title("gtk.STOCK_[Buttons]")
        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda wid: gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.connect("delete_event", lambda a1,a2:gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.set_border_width(10)

        # This horizontal box will contain the columns
        self.boxH = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        self.window.add(self.boxH)

        # Pack the five columns into the HBox
        self.box1 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.boxH.pack_start(self.box1, True, True, 0)
        self.box2 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.boxH.pack_start(self.box2, True, True, 0)
        self.box3 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.boxH.pack_start(self.box3, True, True, 0)
        self.box4 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.boxH.pack_start(self.box4, True, True, 0)
        self.box5 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.boxH.pack_start(self.box5, True, True, 0)

        # Make the list of stock buttons
        stock_file = open('stock_buttons.txt')
        stock_button_list = stock_file.readlines()

        # Slice off excess spaces and line breaks
        i = 0
        for each_string in stock_button_list:
            stock_button_list[i] = stock_button_list[i][2:-1]
            i += 1

        # Pack 15 buttons per column
        i2 = 0
        for button in stock_button_list:
            if i2 < 15:
                self.button1 = gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk, button))
                self.box1.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
                self.button1.show()
                i2 += 1
            elif i2 > 14 and i2 < 30:
                self.button1 = gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk, button))
                self.box2.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
                self.button1.show()
                i2 += 1
            elif i2 > 29 and i2 < 45:
                self.button1 = gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk, button))
                self.box3.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
                self.button1.show()
                i2 += 1
            elif i2 > 44 and i2 < 60:
                self.button1 = gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk, button))
                self.box4.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
                self.button1.show()
                i2 += 1
            elif i2 > 59 and i2 < 75 and button != '':  #Last item in list is empty''
                self.button1 = gtk.Button(stock=getattr(gtk, button))
                self.box5.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
                self.button1.show()
                i2 += 1

        self.box1.show()
        self.box2.show()
        self.box3.show()
        self.box4.show()
        self.box5.show()
        self.boxH.show()
        self.window.show()

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mybuttons = stock_buttons()
    main()
```